# Convert Hex to ASCII in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hex, ascii, string-formatting

I have a series of hex values which looks like this:

```
68 65 6c 6c 6f 57 6f 72 6c 64 7c 31 2f 30 38 31 35 7c 41 42 43 2d 31 35 02 08
```

I now need to convert this hex value to ASCII so that the result looks like:

```
helloWorld|1/0815|ABC-15
```

I tried so many things but I never came to the final code. I tried to use the convert-function in every imaginable way without any success.

At the moment I use [this website](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.htm)  to convert, but I need to do this in my PowerShell script.

Comment: ("68 65 6c 6c 6f 57" -split ' ' |ForEach-Object {[char][byte]"0x$_"}) -join ''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, we can do something terrible and treat the HEX as a string... And then convert it to int16, which then can be converted to a char.

```
$hexString = "68 65 6c 6c 6f 57 6f 72 6c 64 7c 31 2f 30 38 31 35 7c 41 42 43 2d 31 35 02 08"
```

We have the string, now we can use the spaces to split and get each value separately. These values can be converted to an int16, which is a ascii code representation for the character

```
$hexString.Split(" ") | forEach {[char]([convert]::toint16($_,16))}
```

The only problem is that it returns an array of single characters. Which we can iterate through and concatenate into a string

```
$hexString.Split(" ") | forEach {[char]([convert]::toint16($_,16))} | forEach {$result = $result + $_}
$result
```

Answer (score 9):

Much like [Phil P.'s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41762972/712649), but using the `-split` and `-join` operators instead (also, integers not needed, ASCII chars will fit into a `[byte]`):

```
$hexString = "68 65 6c 6c 6f 57 6f 72 6c 64 7c 31 2f 30 38 31 35 7c 41 42 43 2d 31 35 02 08"
$asciiChars = $hexString -split ' ' |ForEach-Object {[char][byte]"0x$_"}
$asciiString = $asciiChars -join ''
$asciiString
```