# Replicating Certutil.exe's -decodehex output exactly

Tags: vb.net, powershell, batch-file, certutil

I have done a ton more research since I first posted this question and I think I had a few terms goofed up as well.

Dilemma:  My company's Information Security team has flagged `certutil.exe` as a potentially dangerous application to be used after a recent phishing attack.  This really stinks because we LOVE `certutil.exe` for the lightning fast and dead-nuts accurate conversion of hex files into ascii files.  These ascii files have to be converted exactly as `certutil.exe -decodehex` performs in order to be parsed by another program to read and interpret various pieces of data produced by a separate in-house program.

I have a `PowerShell` script which seems to convert `Hex` to `ASCII` very accurately, BUT, it never seems to "finish" as though maybe the while loop is dorked up.  Additionally, because of how the stream is is broken down, there are far too many line-breaks in the resulting file. The files are typically 7 MB a piece, roughly 7-8 *billion* characters long, and roughly 11 line breaks.

The script I mention is below and is an adaptation of the work presented [in this link](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/get-hex-dumps-files-powershell).  Instead of converting the data stream into a `Hex` representation of the `Hex` data, I convert it to `ASCII`.

```
$bufferSize = 65536
$ASCIIFile = "C:\FooBar.dat"
$stream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead(
  "C:\FixedOutput.dat")
while ( $stream.Position -lt $stream.Length ) {
#BEGIN CALLOUT A
  $buffer = new-object Byte[] $bufferSize
  $bytesRead = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, $bufferSize)
#END CALLOUT A
  for ( $line = 0; $line -lt [Math]::Floor($bytesRead /
  16); $line++ ) {
  
$slice = $buffer[($line * 16)..(($line * 16) + 15)]

$bytes=[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($slice)
$asc = -join($bytes-split"(..)"|?{$_}|%{[char][convert]::ToByte($_,16)})
$asc | Write-Host >> $ASCIIFile -NoNewline

  }
#BEGIN CALLOUT B
  if ( $bytesRead % 16 -ne 0 ) {
    $slice = $buffer[($line * 16)..($bytesRead - 1)]
    $output = ""
    foreach ( $byte in $slice ) {
      $output=[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($byte)
    }
    $output | ADD-Content $Asciifile
#END CALLOUT B
  }
}


$stream.Close()
```

Additionally, I had adapted the `PowerShell` code from [this S.O. article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762760/convert-hex-to-ascii-in-powershell) in addition to the presumably previous duplicate question and answer.  The problem with this set of code, is the output still took 15 minutes or so, but the output is not identical to `certutil.exe -decodehex` so the information cannot be parsed by our in-house program!

Additionally, I can literally copy and paste the hex data from the original file, paste it into a hex editor and then save the output as a new file to get what I need.

Problem is, we often have 30 - 40 of these files at once and we need a lightning fast solution. . .

I've looked for `VB.net` (my 2nd most familiar language) solutions, but they are comparable in methods as the `PowerShell` methods I have found, and nothing adequately takes an entire file and puts it to `ASCII` with relative ease or Accuracy.

### UPDATE:

In addition to re-formatting the question, I have also put to test the very well-detailed answer below from TheMadTechnician and this brought magnificently glorious tears to my eyes.  If I could reach through the silicon and kiss you, I probably would.  **TEXTBOOK MATCH.  LIGHTNING FAST.  BEAUTIFUL.**

*Now. . . . let us hope my I.S. Dept. doesn't flag this methodology as well and make noise about it. . .*

I modified the `-join` statement since I'm concatenating the files prior to calling `PowerShell` from within a `Batch` script, but this would work beautifully within `PowerShell` as well.

Lastly, since our I.S. Dept. restricts the usage of `.ps1` scripts, a while back, I found an awesome option to embed complex commands as Base64 strings instead and then calling this using `Start /MIN powershell -encodedcommand _insertEncodedCommandHere_`

Again - I cannot thank you enough!  If I ever get a working method utilizing this same `crypt32.dll` library via VB.Net, I'll come back and post it as an answer as well, but YOU have won the prize!

Comment: This site isn't really about "Can you do X?". Try restructuring your question to fix the code you have tried. Include the code, and let us know what is going wrong, and we can help fix it.

Comment: ok, if you don't want to use certutil.exe, how do you feel about the crypt32.dll library?

Comment: I have completely revamped the question, added examples, and marked your answer as the winner.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using the Crypt32.dll library you can add it's CryptStringToBinary method to convert your hex to binary, and then just dump the array to a file.

**Credit where credit is due!** I didn't come up with the conversion bit of this, the crypto genius Vadims Podāns over at Sysadmins LV did. Please check out his post about it here: https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/convert-data-between-binary-hex-and-base64-in-powershell.aspx

So, first we have to add the method from the DLL, we can do that by defining the signature, and using `Add-Type` like this:

```
$signature = @"
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CryptStringToBinary(
    string pszString,
    int cchString,
    int dwFlags,
    byte[] pbBinary,
    ref int pcbBinary,
    int pdwSkip,
    ref int pdwFlags
);
"@
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Namespace PKI -Name Crypt32 -UsingNamespace "System.Text"
```

Mind you, he adds two methods on his page, but for only converting hex to binary we just need the one. He also shows how to go binary to hex, but you can read about that on his page.

Now, you say you have several files you need to merge right? We can just stitch them together in memory and convert them all at once. You don't really say how they're named or how they're ordered, but let's assume they have sequential names (HexFile.01, HexFile.02 and so on). You can figure out how to get them in the right order I'm sure. Let's load them up:

```
$RawHex = (Get-content HexFile.* -raw) -join ''
```

That was easy! So now we have the type added, and we have the original hex formatted file reconstructed in memory, now we just need to convert it to binary and dump it to a file. To do the conversion I'll go ahead and use Vadims' function since it works so well, modified ever so slightly so that it actually outputs the byte array:

```
function Convert-HexToBinary ([string]$hex) {
    # decoding hashtable contains universal flags: Base64Any and HexAny. The function attempts to
    # get the correct input string format and then decode it
    $decoding = @{'Base64Header' = 0; 'Base64' = 1; 'HexRaw' = 12; 'Hex' = 4; 'HexAddr' = 10;
        'HexAscii' = 5; 'HexAddrAscii' = 11; 'Base64Any' = 6; 'HexAny' = 8}
    # initialize variables to receive resulting byte array size and actual input string format
    $pcbBinary = 0
    $pdwFlags = 0
    # call CryptStringToBinary to get resulting byte array size and actual input string format
    if ([PKI.Crypt32]::CryptStringToBinary($hex,$hex.Length,$decoding['HexAny'],$null,[ref]$pcbBinary,0,[ref]$pdwFlags)) {
        # create enough large byte array
        $array = New-Object byte[] -ArgumentList $pcbBinary
        # call the function again to write converted bytes to a byte array
        [void][PKI.Crypt32]::CryptStringToBinary($hex,$hex.Length,$decoding['HexAny'],$array,[ref]$pcbBinary,0,[ref]$pdwFlags)
        $array
    } else {
        Write-Warning $((New-Object ComponentModel.Win32Exception ([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error())).Message)
    }
}
```

Now that function dumps the byte array, and we'll capture that in a variable. Once we have it we can use the `[io.file]` class to write it to a file directly.

```
$BinArr = Convert-HexToBinary $RawHex
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes("C:\Path\To\OutFile.bin",$BinArr)
```

In my own testing this comes out identical to using certutil. I get the same filehash either way I do it.

Comment: This took a moment or two for me to visualize the structure as I'm still learning `PowerShell` but once it finally clicked, I was able to easily modify it for my needs.  Hands down the smoothest, fastest, all-around best-est attempt outside of `certutil.exe` I have ever seen.  I do not know why I am so overjoyed at this, but I am, so thank you.

Comment: If this answer solves the issue please mark it as accepted using the green checkmark to the left of the question.

Comment: I don't know why Stack Overflow did not publish that I clicked the check mark for your answer - I've selected it twice. . . perhaps this is what 'broke' my acceptance.  Forgive me!